# Queuable apex basics

Tags: queueable-apex

I have a method in apex class

```
    public static void test(List<contact> newOppProdList,Map<Id,contact> oldOppProdList){
    
    List<test__c> testprod= [Select Id,name from test__c];
    for(test__c objProjectProd : testprod){
code operations here}
```

I am transferring the method to queuable apex class:

```
public class Queueabletest implements Queueable { 
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
```

I am replacing the query here.

```
        List<test__c> testprod= [Select Id,name from test__c];
         return testprod;
}
```

can i remove the method query in apex class method and i can use same testprod variable in that method ,it will work? and then method parameter values `(List<opportunitylineitem> newOppProdList,Map<Id,opportunitylineitem> oldOppProdList)` is coming for the input as trigger in both after insert and after update.

How can i give the input for queuable class?

for after insert, `contactTriggerHandler.test(trigger.new,null);`

for after update, `contactTriggerHandler.test(trigger.new,trigger.oldMap);`

Answer (score 1):

In your example there appears to be no input for the `Queueable` class.

But in general, you can pass input to a `Queueable` class by defining properties on an instance of the class before you enqueue it. That data is automatically available when the `execute` method is invoked some time later.

```
public class Queueabletest implements Queueable {

    private String v1;
    private Integer v2;

    // Constructor executes now
    public Queueabletest(String v1, Integer v2) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
    }

    // This method will be executed in the future
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // v1 and v2 can be referenced in here
    }
}
```

(The instance is serialized and deserialized to achieve this and not all types are serializable, though the simple types certainly are.)

To run:

```
System.enqueueJob(new Queueabletest('Hello', 123));
```

Comment: Yes you can pass the `Trigger.new` list into your `Queueable`.